# Is there any way to lazily instantiate a member?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to have a struct which lazily instantiates one of it's members, and I am running into lifetime issues.

Here's the approach I have tried:

```rs
pub struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    fn new() -> Bar {
        Bar
    }
}

pub struct Foo {
    bar: Option<Bar>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn bar<'a, 'b>(&'a mut self) -> Result<&'b mut Bar>
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        match &mut self.bar {
            Some(bar) => return Ok(bar),
            None => {}
        }
        let bar = Bar::new();
        self.bar = Some(bar);
        self.bar()
    }
}
```

So here the `bar` function on `Foo` should return `foo.bar` if it exists, and instantiate it first if needed.

When I try to compile, I get this error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.bar` because it is borrowed
   --> crates/foo/foo.rs:125:9
    |
116 |     fn bar<'a, 'b>(&'a mut self) -> Result<&'b mut Bar>
    |                -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
120 |         match &mut self.bar {
    |               ------------- borrow of `self.bar` occurs here
121 |             Some(bar) => return Ok(bar),
    |                                 ------- returning this value requires that `self.bar` is borrowed for `'b`
...
125 |         self.bar = Some(bar);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `self.bar` occurs here
```

Is there any way to implement this pattern, or achieve the same result in Rust?

Comment: I believe you're running into this limitation of the borrow checker: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a limitation of the borrow checker, which requires a workaround of checking if the option is some before borrowing it. The optimizer should be able to compile this code to the same level of performance as what you have.

```
impl Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self) -> Result<&mut Bar, ()> {
        if self.bar.is_some() {
            Ok(self.bar.as_mut().unwrap())
        } else {
            let bar = Bar::new();
            self.bar = Some(bar);
            self.bar()
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc58fbeaab036acf9d10d2da7ab5491e)

Relevant issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663

More information: https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/0.3.1/polonius_the_crab/